# JS three dot operator in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, operator-keyword

I am wondering what does this three dot operator do in this case:

```
const csv = [
            columns
            ...data
        ].map((row) => {
            return Object.values(row).join(",");
        }).join("\n");
```

I am trying to convert data to CSV, and if I assign data in the array without three dots operator like this:

```
const csv = [columns, data].map ...
```

It returns `[object Object]`, while the one with three dot operators returns the correct data.

What does the operator do here?

I want to add a ternary operator but it seems like it's prohibited with a three dots operator.

what I want to achieve:

```
const csv = [
            columns
            (condition) ? ...anotherData : ...data
        ].map ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the spread syntax (`...`) before the conditional operator.

```js
const csv = [columns, ...condition ? anotherData : data];
```

Comment: I would write it as `...(condition ? anotherData : data)` so the precedence is stated explicitly, which make it easier for a human to parse.